# Request info in X-Ray trace from ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-application-load-balancer, aws-xray

In AWS X-Ray if request starts with API Gateway - it populates trace with request info, such as URL or method. But if request initiates with ALB - only trace ID is supplied.

Is there a way supply information similar to API Gateway?

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-services-elb.html):

> Elastic Load Balancing application load balancers add a trace ID to
> incoming HTTP requests in a header named X-Amzn-Trace-Id.
>
> **Load balancers do not send data to X-Ray, and do not appear as a node
> on your service map.**

It looks like if you wanted more information about the request you could possibly tie that back to a record in the [Load Balancer's access log](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-request-tracing.html).